# Add Startups.SE to the list of off-topic sites

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

We've had a few questions lately that, upon reviewing the content, appear to be better-suited for Startups.SE.

- https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3134/9
- https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/3117/9
- [Is there an ideal state in which to incorporate in the USA?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/32/9)

Can we add "Startups" to the off-topic migration sites?

Comment: I'll have a word with the moderators over there, but I'll have to ask what the policy is for this as the migration target here is a beta site.

Comment: This should probably be closed now that Startups.SE no longer exists.